# Is there a way to use firebase using expo react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I will build an offline app using expo react native is that possible ?

if yes can anyone please tell me how ?

Comment: note : I will build an IOS and Android app using expo react native

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look [here](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/). I thik you already asked this ony a comment on one of our previous questions.

For the `offline` features maybe [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-firestore-offline-persistence) can help to.

Comment: [Link only answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) are somewhat discouraged here on SO and from the help *Always quote the most relevant part of an important link*. Also pointing someone to the docs isn't really an answer. If you want to include links, that's fine, but also provide some context as to what answer the link provides (links can break). This should really be a comment, or vote to close the question because it *seriously* needs help (e.g. I 100% agree, the OP needs to read the docs)

Comment: I have already wrote a comment with that link on another question from him that was ignored so tried it this way with a little bit more info for the offline stuff. If he has no direct question I can't do more but point him to a direction with such links. Can't explain someon how to make apps in a comment or answer. The question was also not to general because it also has a point if it is possible to combine some technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out:
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/
TLDR: If you'd like to use Firebase in the Expo Go app with the managed workflow, they recommend using the Firebase JS SDK. It supports Authentication, Firestore & Realtime databases, Storage, and Functions on React Native. Other modules like Analytics are not supported through the Firebase JS SDK, but you can use expo-firebase-analytics for that. If you'd like access to the full suite of native firebase tools, we recommend using the bare workflow and react-native-firebase, because we cannot support this in the Expo Go app currently.

Comment: Hi, if recaptcha always needed when using phone number authentication?

Comment: Instead of a pure bare workflow nowadays... i think you can use the expo dev client to basically get a customized version of Expo Go running (I think it adds plugins like react-native-firebase without needing to go purely Bare Workflow)., Is that correct @Arunim?